# Problem with a conversion of a complexType FROM object TO XML

Tags: xml, web-services, reflection, xml-serialization

For those that like to resolve problems, here's a big one :P

Well, I am developing a system using web services, where I send and receive XML as parameter (not normal parameters as Int, String, bool, etc).

After I receive a XML, I validate the XML with the XSD and also I convert that to an object.. after the process I also convert that object to an XML (validated by XSD) and return as answer of my request of the WS.

Well, my problem: I have complexType that I need to convert it using reflection, but, I am getting problem that I've never saw before.

**My XSD is:**

```
  <xsd:element name="EnviarLoteRpsResposta">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="NumeroLote" type="tsNumeroLote" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="DataRecebimento" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="Protocolo" type="tsNumeroProtocolo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="ListaMensagemRetorno" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
```

**My class (normal class with GETs and SETs):**

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.abrasf.org.br/ABRASF/arquivos/nfse.xsd")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.abrasf.org.br/ABRASF/arquivos/nfse.xsd", IsNullable = false)]
    public class EnviarLoteRpsResposta
    {

        private object[] itemsField;

        private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DataRecebimento", typeof(System.DateTime))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ListaMensagemRetorno", typeof(ListaMensagemRetorno))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NumeroLote", typeof(string), DataType = "nonNegativeInteger")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Protocolo", typeof(string))]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
        public object[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsElementNameField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsElementNameField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How am I using this class?:**

```
EnviarLoteRpsResposta enviarLoteRpsResposta = new EnviarLoteRpsResposta();
enviarLoteRpsResposta.Items = new object[1];
                enviarLoteRpsResposta.Items[0] = DateTime.Now;

                enviarLoteRpsResposta.ItemsElementName = new ItemsChoiceType[1];
                enviarLoteRpsResposta.ItemsElementName[0] = ItemsChoiceType.DataRecebimento;
```

My error happens when I try convert this object to a XML:
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(enviarLoteRpsResposta.GetType());

My error: There was an error reflecting type 'NFSEWS.Models.Bean.EnviarLoteRpsResposta'.

I don't know what do I can do to resolve this..

Comment: Is there some reason you don't simply use "Add Service Reference" to create your client? Why are you doing all of this by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlchoiceidentifierattribute.aspx